# Dynamically add form inputs using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a multi-page form, in which the content of the later pages is dynamically determined by the inputs on the first page of the form. Here's what I'm trying to do:

First Page:

1) Which Company do you use? (choose 1)
- Company Option 1
- Company Option 2
- Company Option 3
- Company Option 4

2) Which Services do you use?
- Service Option 1
- Service Option 2
- Service Option 3
- Service Option 1 & 2
- Service Option 1 & 3
- Service Option 2 $ 3
- Service Option 1,2 & 3

For the second page, I basically want to base the content on what they choose in #1 and #2. For example, if they choose Company Option 2 and Service Option 3, I'd have a list of questions on the next page corresponding to those choices. It would be a different set of questions if the user chose Company Option 4 and Service Option 1,2 & 3.

I suspect using $routeProvider may be the way to go, but I am not sure. As a side note, I'm using Firebase as my backend (so that's where I would save the inputs of the First page). Any help or examples on how to do this would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A typical, non-Angular app might work something like this:

1. User makes choices
2. User hits "next page" button
3. User's choices are sent to server via a synchronous request
4. Server saves choices to DB, does some logic to determine which choices to show the user next, and serves the a page with the correct choices

Using Angular, your flow will look more like this:

1. User makes choices
2. User hits "next page" button
3. Your app looks at what choices the user has made, does some logic to determine which choices to show the user next, hides the part of the DOM containing the current page's choices, and reveals a part of the DOM containing the correct choices (creating the illusion of showing the next page)
4. When the survey is complete, the user hits the "Save" button, sending all of the choices to the server via an asynchronous request
5. Server saves choices to the DB

You can tweak this flow (e.g. add intermediate steps to save choices as the user makes them), but the big difference is that the logic determining which choices to show lives on the client.

Your question about $routeProvider leads me to think you might be interested in allowing users to resume incomplete surveys.  Is that right?  Or are you only interested in the logic behind showing different choices based on prior choices?

EDIT

Let's say you have questions(answers): A(a1, a2), B(b1, b2), and C(c1, c2). Answer a1 will enable question B, and answer a2 will enable question C.

The most important thing to do is to set up your model correctly:

```
scope.survey = {
  "A": {
    "answers": {
      "a1": {
        "enables": "B"
        "picked": false
      },
      "a2": {
        "enables": "C"
        "picked": false
      }
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "answers": {
      "b1": {
        "enables": ""
        "picked": false
      },
      "b2": {
        "enables": ""
        "picked": false
      }
    }
  },
  "C": {
    "answers": {
      "c1": {
        "enables": ""
        "picked": false
      },
      "c2": {
        "enables": ""
        "picked": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then set up your HTML questions, so that each question has an ng-show on it pointing to the correct "picked" property.  For example, the div that encloses your second question would have ng-show = "survey.a.answers.a1.picked".

Setting the value for survey.a.answers.a1.picked depending on what input the user makes is the tricky part.  Not sure how to do that yet!

Comment: I actually am not trying to allow users to resume incomplete surveys, so making it a one-page app is fine. I just want to make sure this solution (showing and hiding parts of the DOM) will show up fine regardless of browser (even if it's mobile).

Comment: CJ, do you know how much of a performance hit it is to have all the choices on one page? If it's just simple questions, how much will it affect load time performance?

Comment: By load time performance, you mean your HMTL file takes a long time to download, right?  I've never had much of a problem with HTML load-time, but you can estimate your final file size by measuring how many kb each survey question adds to the file size, and then multiplying that number by the total number of questions you're going to have.  If load-time becomes a problem, you could run your HTML through a minifier.  Even if load-time becomes an issue, you're better of having a working version of your survey first and then optimizing, rather than optimizing before it's built.

Comment: Just curious, since I have multiple conditions for showing (and ng-switch-when only allows one condition), how do you best recommend to have sections hide/show based on the multiple conditions?

Comment: maybe ng-if is the answer? If also been thinking about ng-hide and ng-class, but seems to be many possibilities.